# Replacement of fflush(stdin)

Tags: c

I have the below code,

```
fflush(stdin);
print("Enter y/n");
scanf("%c",&a);
```

Here,it is quitting before giving the input.it looks like the issue is because it is not flushing out the input buffer which might be having some junk characters.Is there any alternative for flush(stdin).This code snippet is working in Solaris but it is not working in Linux.

Comment: First line of `man fflush` reads: *The function `fflush()` forces a **write** of all user-space buffered data for the given **output or update** stream*. cnicutar has the right answer for how to skip unwanted input, but in addition to that you *should* read the docs of the functions you're using. *And* check their return value... as your call above will have returned `EOF` and set `errno = EBADF` to signal your wrongful use of the function. Ignoring return values is bad, bad, bad...

Comment: See also [Using `fflush(stdin)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).

Answer (score 16):

This is well explained in the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfinterlace.html). See also: [explanation](http://c-faq.com/stdio/gets_flush2.html). The proposed solutions:

- **Quit using scanf. Use `fgets` and the `sscanf`**
- Use this to eat the newline

  ```
  while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
  /* discard the character */;
  ```

The fact that flushing stdin works on some implementations **[is wrong](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html)**.

> Some vendors do implement fflush so
>   that fflush(stdin) discards unread
>   characters, although portable programs
>   cannot depend on this.

Answer (score 3):

For C on GNU

you can use

```
__fpurge(stdin);
```

include stdio_ext.h header for accessing the function. Though the post is very old still I thought this might help some linux developers.

Comment: This is horrible, even if it works as intended. Imagine what happens if the input is coming from a file or a pipe.

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf(" %c",&c);
```

or

```
scanf(" ");
//reading operation (gets(), fgets(stdin,...) etc)
```

Spaces in the scanf() format string will ignore any whitespace until the first non-whitespace.