# Why won't fflush(stdin) work?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin)

My code is:

```
scanf("%d", &_choice);
fflush(stdin);
gets(input);
```

I use `fflush(stdin);` to remove the `'\n'` character that was left after `scanf`.

However, I found out that it doesn't work, and `gets` automatically takes the `'\n'` char and continues.

I solved it by using `getchar()` instead of `fflush` but I still can't figure out why didn't `fflush` work...

**Edit:** I understand now `fflush` is for output streams only. 
But is there a command for "cleaning" `stdin` from junk?

Comment: It's undefined behavior. Period.

Comment: Also, you're using gets(). Don't. Use fgets() instead.

Comment: @milleniumbug I don't want to deal with removing last `\n` character

Comment: @cookya You prefer buffer overruns? Also, `gets()` has finally been removed from the language.

Comment: [What to use instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6277391/1012936)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `fflush` is for output streams.

And at any rate, `fflush` is not for "removing `\n` characters"...

Comment: Then what does `fflush(stdin)` do?
And how can `\n` characters be moved from stdin / stdout ?

Comment: @cookya It's an error. `fflush` writes buffered data (i.e. data that hasn't been written yet) to the specified output stream. `stdin` is not an output stream.

Comment: @cookya: It's undefined behaviour; anything could happen.

Comment: For what it's worth, `fflush(stdin)` *is defined* on POSIX systems, but only in the case where `stdin` is seekable. It's undefined for unseekable streams. This is of course really stupid...