# fopen can't read a file(file always equal to NULL)

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, fgets

I'm programming in code::blocks and I got problem reading file here is the code:

```
            char fileName[] ="";
            fflush(stdin);
            E11: printf("\n\tEnter the @ Mac (X:X:X:X:X:X) in Hex :");
            gets(MAC);
            E12: printf("\n\tEnter file name:");
            gets(fileName);
            FILE* fichier;
            fichier = fopen(fileName,"r");
            if (fichier == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error! Try Again");
                goto E12;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("sending Data....");
                //TODO..
            }
```

Comment: Doing `fflush(stdin)` is explicitly marked as undefined behavior in the C specification. Some standard libraries implement it, but if you want to be portable or standards-compliant you should not do that.

Comment: Also, don't use labels and `goto` as loops, use actual loops. C might have started out as a high-level assembly kind of language, but it's not anymore.

Comment: Don't use `goto` in this situation.

Comment: i forget to mention that i used 'scanf()' and 'getch()' before this code.

Comment: i tried this too **'fichier = fopen("file.txt","r");'** but nothing new.

Comment: thanks to all my problem is solved i explained under.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, **don't use `gets()`, use [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) instead.**

`gets()` seriously suffers from buffer overrun issue, which can be avoided by using `fgets()`.

That said, coming to the *main* issue in your code, by saying

```
char fileName[] ="";
```

you're allocating a 1-char array, which is not enough to hold the input, anyway.

You should change that to

```
char fileName[64] = {0};
```

or something similar.

Also, `fflush(stdin);` is against the `C` standard,  it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Remove that statement.

Comment: Doing `char fileName[64] = "";` would `0`-out all of `fileName` as well.

Comment: but 'fgets()' reads from file ins't it wich is not my case here.

Comment: @alk Absolutely, matter of choice, sir. :)

Comment: @Konnichiwasad use `stdin` as input file. :)

Answer (score 0):

This program exhibits undefined behavior. `filename` is a `char` array with only one element. Try changing the declaration to `char fileName[256] = "";`

Answer (score 0):

1. [`fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277370/replacement-of-fflushstdin)
2. `gets` is bad. From `man gets`:

   > Never use `gets()`.  Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the
   >      data  in  advance  how  many  characters  `gets()` will read, and because
   >      `gets()` will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it
   >      is  extremely  dangerous  to  use.   It has been used to break computer
   >      security.  **Use `fgets()` instead**.

   *(Emphasis and code formatters added.)*
3. The definition

   ```
   char fileName[] = "";
   ```

   only allocates one byte of memory because `sizeof("") == 1`. You need a more flexible approach, which is another argument for `fgets`. Just allocate some arbitrary number of bytes probably capable of storing the whole input and pass that size to `fgets`:

   ```
   char fileName[32];

   ...

   fgets(fileName, sizeof(fileName), stdin);
   ```
4. [`goto` is bad.](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html)

Comment: Right, but there is another **major** issue in the code. :)

Comment: @SouravGosh Working on it.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all:

after trying and trying if found that the problem is the file that i'm trying to read which is *lorem ipsum* that i copied from: [here](http://www.faux-texte.com/dummy-paragraphs-big-1.htm).
i can't belive it, it is so strange..

thanks for the answers.