# flushig the buffer in c

Tags: c, buffer

I am runing my code but it doesn't let me give it an input as i told.

I suspect it to be a buffer problem related to c language. However i tried
flushing the buffer using `fflush(stdin)` before the problems input and after it.

so the first input is here:

```
do {

printf("Welcome to Full Adder\n");
printf("(1)Compute and display the outputs\n(2)Quiet\nYou choose: ");
scanf("%d", &QorR);
fflush(stdin);
printf("You have chosen option %d\n",QorR)
```

as you could see theirs an fflush there ust after i give it the input

the code with the problem is as follows:

```
for(A=0, B=0, C_in=0, D=0; BBase==8 ;BBase == 0){       
        A=0;B=0;C_in=0;D=0;

        fflush(stdin);
        printf("enter a number"); //"it stops exactly here"
        scanf("%c",&D);         //%c to be able to compare it to it's ASCII value
                                //i think thats why theirs
            if (D > 067){
                printf("Octal %d cannot be represented with 3 bits! Please try again!",D);continue;
            }//go back to input


            C_in=D%2;
            D=D/2;

            B=D%2;
            D=D/2;

            A=D%2;
            D=D/2;


            switch (A) {

                case 1:
```

and it jumps to the end of the loop. Can someone help me with this problem?
the funny thing is that it works perfectly at BBase==2, but at BBase==16&BBase==8 it doesn't, although the three of them are written the same way.

---

**Update**
I put a `scanf(%d,&scrap);` just befor the `enter a number`message and it waited for me to give it an input. how so?

---

**Update**
Problem solved!
Added `__fpurge(stdin)` and it's working in a better way now.
Thanks to all the engagement in the comments.

Comment: I'm working on ubuntu if the OS has a relation to the problem

Comment: More people will be able to help you if you give a MCVE. However: `fllush(stdin)` is not actually defined by the standard, and most implementations have it clear any input that has yet to be read. That won’t help you here.

Comment: I also doubt that the loop in your second fragment sets its variables correctly, but it’s impossible to tell.

Comment: can you provide entire code..?

Comment: You are having one of the common problems with `scanf`.  You do indeed have a problem with extra characters lurking in your input buffer -- however, `fflush(stdin)` is *not* the way to fix them.  See [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277370/replacement-of-fflushstdin) for hints.

Comment: so `fpurge()` will help?

Comment: @SteveSummit is there any other way in taking input in C other than `scanf()`? something with the feature of `endl;` in C++

Comment: @SanadAlArousi Yes.  You can read one line using `fgets()`.  (It does have the issue that it leaves the `\n` character in the string, so sometimes you have to take steps to remove it.)  `scanf` is typically used only in introductory texts and classes; it is not generally used and is not recommended for "real" programs.

Comment: The loop is definitely fishy to say the least: the last Argument to it, `BBase==10` is without side-effects, its value never used. Sure you want *this* exactly *there*?

Comment: @MichaelBeer i didn't get what you mean

Comment: @Sanad Well, your loop head is: `for(A=0, B=0, C_in=0, D=0; BBase==8 ;BBase == 0)` which means: When entering the loop, do `A=0, B=0, C_in=0, D=0;` which is reasonable. Then in each Iteration check whether `BBase==8` is true and exit the loop if not. Also plausible (at the first glance at least). And then if not exited, do `BBase==0` which is useless to say the least. `BBase==0` just compares `BBase` to `0`,  nothing beyond. You could replace the head of your loop with `for(A=0, B=0, C_in=0, D=0; BBase==8;;)` or  `for(BBase==0,  A=0, B=0, C_in=0, D=0; BBase==8;;)` .

Comment: Just drop the last semicolon in the 2 last for loop heads - typo. I am  on my mobile... Anyhow, I strongly suspect that you wanted something else as the third argument to the loop. I mean, you are not even aware of it which indicates it did not happen on purpose...

Comment: @MichaelBeer I noticed this now. Thanks a lot. Even my colleague when I stopped by to him to help me, he didn't notice this one.