# Save pointer to structure into an array of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am having a hard time getting an array of pointer to structures to save and retrieve the data I filled, the code snippet has the core of my program.

I was able to make the program itself work using an array of struct, but I figure that is more memory intensive and I am trying to only realloc the array of pointers to the structures instead of all the structs at each loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct dados_aluno {
    int matricula;
    char nome[60];
    int situacao;
    float nota1, nota2, nota3, media;
}dados_aluno;

int main(void){
    int done = 0;
    int i;
    int n_alunos = 0;
    int matricula_atual;

    dados_aluno *novo_aluno;
    dados_aluno **alunos_da_turma;
    alunos_da_turma = malloc(sizeof(dados_aluno*));
    while (done == 0){
        printf("Matricula: ");
        scanf("%d", &matricula_atual);
        fflush(stdin);//scanf followed by gets = bad time!
        if (matricula_atual == -1){
            done = 1;
            continue;
        }
        n_alunos++;
        novo_aluno = calloc(1, sizeof(dados_aluno));
        novo_aluno->matricula = matricula_atual;

        printf("\nNome: ");
        gets(novo_aluno->nome);

        //the code below rises warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        //and returns garbage on the for loop at the end of the program
        alunos_da_turma[n_alunos - 1] = &novo_aluno;
        //using memcpy instead doesnt rise an error, but the first field is garbage and the 3º interation of the loop crashes
        //memcpy(alunos_da_turma[n_alunos -1],&novo_aluno,sizeof(dados_aluno *));
        alunos_da_turma = realloc(alunos_da_turma, (sizeof(dados_aluno *) * (n_alunos + 1)));
    }
    for (i=0;i<(n_alunos);i++){
            printf("%d  %s\n",alunos_da_turma[i]->matricula,alunos_da_turma[i]->nome);
    }
}
```

I expect to dynamic allocate a struct "dados_alunos" and also dynamic allocate an array of pointers to said structs, insert user input "nome" and "matricula_atual" to the fields of the struct "dados_alunos" and be able to read them after exiting the while loop.
On trying to save the address to the current struct to the array using

```
alunos_da_turma[n_alunos - 1] = &novo_aluno;
```

gives the warning "assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]" and seems to save to all the positions of the array the first pointer/garbage written to it no matter how many interactions.
Using memcpy instead store garbage on the first field if I only try one interaction and crashes within 2 interactions or more on the while loop.

Comment: Better use `sizeof` with the name of the variable, and not its type. Example: instead of `alunos_da_turma = malloc(sizeof(dados_aluno*));` use `alunos_da_turma = malloc(sizeof(*alunos_da_turma));`.  If you change the type of the variable later, the code doesn't break.

Comment: This: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour. It should NEVER be used.

Comment: I removed the fflush, using the suggestion to use fgets, it doesnt seems to get me into problems that a scanf followed by gets without clearing the buffer did.

Comment: Yes, it didnt really work either way. I had a different issue that has many answers here, using fflush(stdin) ON windows seems the easier solution, but I did read it was not suppose to work. The issue is, after the line scanf("%d", var), the stdin buffer keeps an "\n" + anything other then an int typed, soo when I called gets(string_var), instead of asking for input, stdin dumped "\n" on it. Using fgets() still has this problem, but I will look into it here, there were many solutions when I was looking into it before.

Comment: You can remove the newline from stdin before `fgets`, but not with `fflush` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277370/replacement-of-fflushstdin);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> alunos_da_turma[n_alunos - 1] = &novo_aluno;
> ```

is refused because `alunos_da_turma` is a `dados_aluno **` so `alunos_da_turma[n_alunos - 1]` is a `dados_aluno *`, but `novo_aluno` is a `dados_aluno *` so `&novo_aluno` is a `dados_aluno **`

you wanted

```
alunos_da_turma[n_alunos - 1] = novo_aluno;
```

---

Warning

> ```
> gets(novo_aluno->nome);
> ```

is dangerous (and deprecated since years) because if the input string is greater than 59 characters you write out of the field with an unexpected behavior, do

```
fgets(novo_aluno->nome, sizeof(novo_aluno->nome), stdin);
```

However except if you enter the name on the same line you enter the matricula you will get an empty line because the rest of the line/newline is not flush by `fflush(stdin);`, *fflush* does not work out of a file

If the name cannot contain separator use `scanf("%59s", novo_aluno->nome);` rather than *fgets*, else bypass characters up to the newline explicitely

Note also in

> ```
> alunos_da_turma = realloc(alunos_da_turma, (sizeof(dados_aluno *) * (n_alunos + 1)));
> ```

you reallocate with one extra element, you already increased `n_alunos`

Doing

```
int done = 0;
...
while (done == 0){
    ...
    if (matricula_atual == -1){
        done = 1;
        continue;
    }
    ...
}
```

is quite complicated for nothing and can be replaced by

```
for (;;) {
  ...
  if (matricula_atual == -1)
    break;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes I increased n_alunos, but its start value is 0, on the first loop it would not allocate memory for two pointers without the "+1".Thanks for the answer as a whole, it solved more then one problem!

Answer (score 1):

`alunos_da_turma[X]` is a pointer to struct dados_aluno, not a pointer to a pointer to a struct dados_aluno.
What would be valid is `alunos_da_turma[n_alunos-1] = novo_aluno`

So, some solution for general problem:

```
dados_alunos** alunos_da_turma = malloc (10 * sizeof(dados_aluno*)); //array for 10 pointers
int length = 0;  //number of inserted alunos_dados elements
int size = 10;  //number of allocated pointers spaces
while(done == 0){
//ask for input
    dados_aluno* novo_aluno = malloc (sizeof(dados_aluno));
    novo_aluno->matricula = //input
    //etc
    dados_alunos[length] = novo_aluno;
    length++;
    if (length == size){
         dados_alunos = realloc(dados_alunos, 2 * size * sizeof(dados_aluno*));
         size += size; //doubles size
    }
}
```